# Take a digit of a string as an integer in C++

Tags: c++, string, integer

I want to add the first digit of a string `111` to the integer `x = 0` so that it equals

`x = 0 + 1 = 1`

The following code takes the character `1` instead of the integer `1`:

```
int x = 0;
string str = "111";
x += str[1];
```

`std::stoi` did not work either:

`x += std::stoi(str[1]);`

Comment: `stoi` didn't work because `stoi` according to the cpp reference takes a `string` as a parameter, not a `char`. `str[1]` is a single character, not a `string`.

Answer (score 2):

The simple way to convert a digit to an integer is to substract `'0'` from it.

```
x += str[0] - '0';
```

This works because the *encodings* of the decimal digits are guaranteed to be continuous. So subtracting the lowest digit gives you the digit value.

Your other error is that the first character of a string is `str[0]` not `str[1]`.